# Reset PDF Page Rotation to 0

Tags: pdf, pdf-lib.js

PDF has stored rotation value which is multiple of 90 degrees.

I want to reset the value to 0 without actually rotating it. Is there any way to do that by programmatically? If possible, I want to use https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib

similar issues bellow

- https://community.apryse.com/t/reset-pdf-page-rotation-to-0/2747
- https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/issues/587

fyi
Below is PDF rotated 90 deg.
https://github.com/shuntagami/sharp-resize/files/10849254/90.pdf

Comment: A generic solution is very complex. In particular you have to consider all the annotations with their diverse coordinate entries and JavaScript code pieces that play around with coordinates. As the final comment in the thread on the Apryse page you referred to indicates, they cheated and flattened all annotations... Maybe you should instead try work with non-0 page rotation values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `upright` from coherentpdf.js does this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/coherentpdf

Alternatively, to roll your own, just:

a) swap the dimensions of the page

b) set the rotation to 0

c) calculate a suitable transformation matrix, and prepend it to the page. Be careful - a page might not start at (0,0)

d) harder: also move annotations, links etc to match.

e) much harder: some patterns might change when you do this: rework the pattern matrices too (this is from memory, not 100% sure).

Comment: Thank you so much! The upright function do what I want!